# How Add Achnor to taxonomy link

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, add-filter

I'm trying to place an anchor in my code
so that the links point to **#here**

for exemple

mysite/property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_type:9 **#here**

```
add_filter('term_link', function ($termlink, $term, $taxonomy) {
   
    // taxonomy type
    if ('property_type' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_type:' . $term->term_id;  
    }
    
    // taxonomy city
    if ('property_city' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_city:' . $term->term_id;
    }
    
    return $termlink;
}, 10, 3);
```

it seems to me that it must be `.$anchor. '#here';`

but it seems this is not the right way..(PHP fatal error)

```
add_filter('term_link', function ($termlink, $term, $taxonomy) {
   
    // taxonomy type
    if ('property_type' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_type:' . $term->term_id; . $anchor . '#here';
    }
    
    // taxonomy city
    if ('property_city' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_city:' . $term->term_id; . $anchor . '#here';
    }
    
    return $termlink;
}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You Just need to remove semicolon after `$term->term_id`
> so Final code will look like below

```
add_filter('term_link', function ($termlink, $term, $taxonomy) {
    if ('property_type' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_type:' . $term->term_id . $anchor . '#here';
    }
    if ('property_city' == $taxonomy) {
        $termlink = trailingslashit(get_home_url()) . 'property/?jsf=jet-engine&tax=property_city:' . $term->term_id . $anchor . '#here';
    }
    return $termlink;
}, 10, 3);
```